# Python JSON спарсить все данные по ключу views

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, парсер, wikipedia

[Статистика Википедия](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/per-article/en.wikipedia/all-access/all-agents/Albert_Einstein/daily/2015010100/2020022500)

Как получить список всех "views", числа типа: 16944,15420....

Comment: стандартную библиотеку json подключаешь и пошла-пошла

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разделяйте задачу на части:

- Получение данных по ссылке. Например, модуль "из коробки" [urllib.request.urlopen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) или сторонний, но очень удобный [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests)
- Парсинг данных в json. Для этого использует одноименный модуль "из коробки": [json.load](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html#json.load)
- Обработка данных: коллекции, циклы, и т.п.

Все вместе:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

url = 'https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/per-article/en.wikipedia/all-access/all-agents/Albert_Einstein/daily/2015010100/2020022500'

data = json.load(urlopen(url))
items = []

for item in data['items']:
    items.append(item['views'])

print(items)
# [16001, 16944, 15420, 14219, 15557, 16272, 15921, 16604, 15124, 13800, ...
```